# Performing Segue from within a View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I have a custom class named `MenuBar` which is a `UIView` used to present a `UICollectionView` to a view controller.  The problem I'm having is using a segue to another view controller when a `UICollectionViewCell` is selected. Since `MenuBar` is not a view controller, I can't seem to call `performSegue()`.  I created a segue in my storyboard between the two view controllers with an identifier. How can I properly trigger a segue from within my custom view class? How would this normally be done?  I tried making a new instance of my view controller so that I could us the `.performSegue()` from within the `didSelectItemAt` `collectionView` function but I don't think this is the proper way to do it at all. example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = UARTModuleViewController()
    vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "colorSelection", sender: nil)
}
```

Any suggestions on how to perform the segue from within this function would be greatly appreciated. Below I will supply the key components of my existing code so that you can see what I'm doing. There is a lot more code in both classes but I think this should be enough for the general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

**view controller:**

```
class UARTModuleViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setupMenuBar()
    }

    let menuBar: MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        return mb
    }()

    private func setupMenuBar() {
        view.addSubview(menuBar)

        menuBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        menuBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    }
}
```

**MenuBar.swift:**

```
class MenuBar : UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCollectionView()
    }

    private func setupCollectionView() {
        self.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = UARTModuleViewController() // I want to perform a segue from here
        vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "colorSelection", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide helpful advice and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
let vc = UARTModuleViewController()
```

Creates another object on the fly that's independent of the presented one and may cause a crash if the vc isn't programmatically created , instead you need a delegate

```
lazy var menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar()
    mb.delegate = self
    return mb
}()
```

And add this var inside `MenuBar`

```
weak var delegate:UARTModuleViewController?
```

Then use it like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    delegate?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "colorSelection", sender: nil)
}
```

Should say that a better approach for reusability is to create a protocol

```
protocol ColManager { 
   func navigate()
}
```

With

```
weak var delegate:ColManager?
```

And any class that wants to use should conform to the protocol and implement the `navigate` method

Comment: this makes a lot more sense to me. However, when I now call `mb.delegate = self` after making the suggested changes, I receive this error on the same line **Cannot assign value of type '(UARTModuleViewController) -> () -> (UARTModuleViewController)' to type 'UARTModuleViewController?'**

Comment: made it `lazy var menuBar: MenuBar` ?

Comment: ahh i missed that edit. this worked perfectly! thank you for the help! it makes a lot more sense using the  `weak var delegate:UARTModuleViewController?` and assigning it to `self`